# How to make Kotlin Multiplatform (for Desktop) into a "Single Instance App"?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, single-instance

Is there a way or any documentation describing how to turn a Kotlin Multiplatform app for Windows Desktop into a "Single Instance App"?

My intention is if a user clicks again on the app's launcher/executable when it's already running, it just pulls up the existing running instance to the user's view, instead of starting up a new instance of the app. But I haven't found any Java or Gradle or Multiplatform etc. feature flag or code to figure out how this can be done.